# Google Search showing "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions ..."

Tags: discussion, bug, google, search-engine

When searching for some help on a topic on XML Namespaces, I encountered the following in my Google search:

> [image: snapshot of search results]

The 2nd item in search results pointed to [Why "Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' is not available to be referenced in this schema."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405223/why-namespace-http-www-w3-org-xml-1998-namespace-is-not-available-to-be-ref) however, the title of the question is no where close to what the title is as it appears in the Google search.

I was logged into google and Stack Overflow at the time. The search string was ["namespace not available to be referenced in this schema"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=namespace%20not%20available%20to%20be%20referenced%20in%20this%20schema) (without quotes).

Comment: What is your exact search term?

Comment: Yeah, reproduced. Weird!

Comment: I was able to reproduce this once about 30 min ago, but no longer can. Curios if it is due to a Google caching hiccup?

Comment: @SamB. still showing the same for me.

Comment: I can reproduce it on my my macbook but not in any browser on my iPhone. [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=namespace+not+available+to+be+referenced+in+this+schema&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=namespace+not+available+to+be+referenced+in+this+schema&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9703553761974b7188ddd72ea173c198) and [Yahoo](https://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AgqRxXqmnWudD0381C8N3mybvZx4?p=namespace+not+available+to+be+referenced+in+this+schema&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-901&fp=1) don't seem to have the same issue--I blame Google.